# oracle em does not show any administrations options

Tags: oracle

I want to try some administration tasks on the new version (19) of Oracle database like add a new user or edit user rights on the em. So I downloaded the oracle vm.

I tried to connect to oracle enterprise manager express in the oracle vm with 2 defualt users "system" and "sys" and the default password "oracle". But I can not find any tabs or buttons for administration purpose like old versions with  different tabs like "availability", "Security", "Schemas"

I tried as well with the user "SYSMAN" and password "oracle" but I got "Invalid Database Credentials" error. Because there is no username with this name.

These two are the screen shots of new version without any administration tabs:

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAjQ5.jpg)

[em concle after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IURDP.jpg)

This is a example of the em console on the oracle 12c with the administration tabs und buttons:

[em on the old version 12c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Mim.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to enable the Flash version of OEM express, run this code in sqlplus with sys user as sysdba:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/execemx emx
```

and then install flash player on the firefox browser:

```
# rpm -ivh http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
# rpm –import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux
# yum -y install flash-plugin
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least OEM 13.3.2 /before/ the 31st of December, 2020, by which time Adobe Flash will be *dead* in /all/ browsers.

Comment: How can I do that?